# DNN Hotcakes checkout address

Tags: e-commerce, dotnetnuke

We have a requirement not to allow any address with "PO Box".If a user enters "PO Box" in the address field, we need to display an error message. How can this be accomplished in Hotcakes checkout process? Do we need to use integration pipeline or some Jquery?

Comment: did you try something ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you could do one or the other, or both.  If you do both, it would be a better user experience with instant feedback, combined with server-side validation.  It's really up to you.  Regardless, I'd highly suggest using the action delegate integration pipeline as a server-side catch-all.

Comment: I did try to add validation using integration pipeline. I can check if the address has PO.Box then abort and display abort message. How can I add this error message as part of error message summary? Like if we do not enter first name or last name and try to place an order, an error message appears on the top. I want the PB. Box is not allowed message to be part of that stack.

Comment: You'll find an example of giving customers feedback in the default sample project code for the action delegate pipeline solution.